# Python implementation to generate Delaunay triangulation based spatial weight matrix

Tags: python, software-recommendations, pysal, delaunay

I'm looking for Python implementation for Delaunay triangulation based spatial weights.
There are a lot of spatial weights techniques available in a Python geospatial library `PySAL` but Delaunay triangulation based weights are not there.

Where can I find a Python implementation to generate Delaunay triangulation based weights matrix for polygon data.

Comment: Did you look at scipy.spatial.delaunay? Tell us what you have tried so far. I always start with a Google search.

Comment: [softwarerecs.se] is the SE place for software recommendations. GIS SE tries to steer clear of *opinion-based* questions which will attract marketers forevermore.

Comment: @wingnut I researched that library earlier and it continuous. I was able to generate Delaunay triangulation for my polygon data after converting them to centroids. But i don't know how to finish it in the form of  spatial weight matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Lostman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/72434/lostman) suggests,  you can form the centroids for the polygons. To build weights, you can then use PySAL to form "voronoi weights" using the centroids as generator points, as shown in the [pysal tutorial](https://pysal.org/libpysal/notebooks/voronoi.html).